# Optional Parameters in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, automation, keyword, keyword-argument, params-keyword

I'm new to Vb-script and I have to create a function (keyword) which needs a big number of param but using Optional parameters is not allowed in Vb-script.

I did some web research and I noticed that I can use argument array or objects dictionary. I want to know in which case it is preferred to use argument array and when I have to use Dictionary. Also, is it easy to add param to my function arguments in each case ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a class for all your parameters, and pass a single instance of that class.  It's a bad design to have methods with a large number of parameters, and if you use an array, it's less robust because you'll always have to count to figure out which index your param is at.  With a class, all your "parameters" will be named fields or properties.

Here's a simple example of what I'm talking about:

```
Dim cfg : Set cfg = New CarConfig

With cfg
    .MakeName = "Ford"
    .ModelName = "Escort"
    .StyleName = "2-Door"
    .ColorName = "Blue"
    .NumWheels = 4
End With

Call BuildCar(cfg)

Sub BuildCar(usingConfig)
    With usingConfig
        Call MsgBox( "Your " & .ColorName & " " & _
            .StyleName & " " & .MakeName & " " & _
            .ModelName & " has: " & _
            cfg.NumWheels & " wheels.")
    End With
End Sub

Class CarConfig
    Public MakeName
    Public ModelName
    Public NumWheels
    Public ColorName
    Public StyleName
End Class
```

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking too about using a class to encapsulate all my parameters and to create a method add_paramater and call it each time I need to add a paramater to this class what do you think please ?

Comment: Well, what I meant was you create a class that has a static set of named properties, not a collection of parameters.  Otherwise, you would have to address your parameters by name, and what if the name of your parameter changes and you forget to change the string value addressing your parameter?  It could lead to bugs and  thus it's not as robust.

Comment: you are right, I was thinking about having a class with a collection of parameters and or each param I have a getter and a setter but I did not think about this case if I change the name of a param. So, could you please give more details about how can I use a static set of named properties because I'm new to VBS.If you can please give me an example.

Comment: I tried to apply your solution for my case but I think it is not the required one: in my situation I have an excel test to be run in UFT and I have a keyword Add_Car for example. In the excel sheet I have to enter values for all the parameters of this keyword. After entering the parameters values in the excel sheet it will be runned in UFT.

Comment: Oh now that's different.  I didn't realize you were getting a *dynamic* set of values.  In that case, yes, you should look at using a dictionary.

Comment: yeah, This is my problem. Thank you sooo much for your help @rory.ap